# Is there a 64bit desktop for the Raspberry Pi 4B?

Tags: raspberrypi

I'm hoping to get the standard 64bit Ubuntu desktop on the 8GB RPi.
Does this animal exist?

Answer (score 2):

The page:

https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi

says the 64 bit Ubuntu Desktop version 21.04 is available for:

Raspberry Pi 400, Raspberry Pi CM4

I am happy to confirm it also runs on a Pi4 and for me it is a big improvement over 20.10.

I had a problem with 21.04 initially but having clicked the button to switch from Wayland to Xorg it now works perfectly. The Wayland issue seems to be related to the use of a Logitech wireless keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's described in the tutorial on the Ubuntu website:

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-your-raspberry-pi#5-install-a-desktop

The standard desktop is: `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

You can also choose another desktop flavor among these:

https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours

This blog post comments on the efficiency and suitability of some of the desktop flavors.

https://waldorf.waveform.org.uk/2020/ubuntu-desktops-on-the-pi.html